How to update excel formula to work for all columns continuously to the right and not just the current 2 it's set up for
I have a Group History tab that I keep a record of what group each student gets put in. Screenshot of contents of Group History tab:

The other tab named History Matrix I've gotten to successfully count how many times each student has been in a group with another student and I was able to drag the handle to dynamically update it for the other cells.
Screenshot of contents of History Matrix tab:

The problem is, this is currently set up to only work with those 2 columns of dates and I would have to update the formula for future dates and it would become a bothersome. There's also, with the way it's currently written, if I delete any columns before N, then it would throw it off because some of the formula is using INDIRECT which mentions those column names by string text and not actually connecting the the columns to dynamically update with them.
Here is the formula currently in cell B3 of the History Matrix:
=IF(B$2=$A3, "x", SUM((--('Group History'!$N3=INDIRECT("Group History!$N"&COLUMN(B$2)+1))) + (--('Group History'!$O3=INDIRECT("Group History!$O"&COLUMN(B$2)+1)))))

Link to view the spreadsheet
Link to make a copy
I've tried ChatGPT premium and it just ran in circles and was no help.

Which app are you using, Sheets or Excel? If Excel, which version?

Thanks for sharing copy of the data - it made it very convenient.

If you replace the volatile INDIRECT with INDEX, you'll get this =IF(B$2=$A4,"x",SUM((--('Group History'!$N4=INDEX('Group History'!$N:$N,COLUMN(B$2)+1)))+(--('Group History'!$O4=INDEX('Group History'!$O:$O,COLUMN(B$2)+1))))). Does it yield the expected result?

With Microsoft 365, you could try this:
=LET(
    students, 'Group History'!A3:A28,
    grp_assigned, 'Group History'!B3:AD28,
    num_students, ROWS(students),
    st_indices, SEQUENCE(num_students),
    num_shared, LAMBDA(x, y,
        IF(
            x = y,
            "x",
            SUM(
                --BYCOL(
                    CHOOSEROWS(grp_assigned, x, y),
                    LAMBDA(c, IF(SUM(--(LEN(TRIM(c)) = 0)), 0, ROWS(UNIQUE(c)) = 1))
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    history_matrix, MAKEARRAY(num_students, num_students, num_shared),
    HSTACK(VSTACK("", students), VSTACK(TOROW(students), history_matrix))
)

Result:

Iterating two (student) rows at a time, then by each (date) column:

Set column count = 0 if there are blanks SUM(--(LEN(TRIM(c)) = 0))
If shared, the unique count will be 1 ROWS(UNIQUE(c)) = 1

Please adjust the range B3:AD28 according to possible future entries.

Google Sheets
Seems to work with some adjustments:

in BYCOL, with --(ROWS(UNIQUE(c)) = 1)
to check blank rows sum(--byrow(c, lambda(a, len(trim(a)) = 0)))

=LET(
    students, 'Group History'!A3:A28,
    grp_assigned, 'Group History'!B3:AD28,
    num_students, ROWS(students),
    st_indices, SEQUENCE(num_students),
    num_shared, LAMBDA(x, y,
        IF(
            x = y,
            "x",
            SUM(
                BYCOL(
                    CHOOSEROWS(grp_assigned, x, y),
                    LAMBDA(c, IF(sum(--byrow(c, lambda(a, len(trim(a)) = 0))), 0, --(ROWS(UNIQUE(c)) = 1)))
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    history_matrix, MAKEARRAY(num_students, num_students, num_shared),
    result, HSTACK(VSTACK("", students), VSTACK(TOROW(students), history_matrix)),
result
)



Assuming your tables both start in cell A1, in 'Group History'!B2, enter:
 =IF($A2<>B$1,SUMPRODUCT((XLOOKUP($A2,'Group History'!$A$3:$A$28,'Group History'!$B$3:$S$28, 0,0)=XLOOKUP(B$1,'Group History'!$A$3:$A$28,'Group History'!$B$3:$S$28,0,0))*(XLOOKUP($A2,'Group History'!$A$3:$A$28,'Group History'!$B$3:$S$28, 0,0)<>"")),"x")

and copy the formula down and to the right.

One way to get that with an array formula that continues filling down and to the right automatically is to first unpivot the data into a row-oriented format, and then iterate students, counting the number of times they're in the same group with every other student separately.
To unpivot the data, Insert > Sheet, name the new sheet Unpivot, and put this formula in cell A1:
=let( 
  unpivot_, lambda(data, numFixedCols, numColsPerGroup, let(k,n(numFixedCols),d,if(k,data,hstack(sequence(rows(data)),data)),f,if(k,k,1),g,numColsPerGroup,s,lambda(r,c,h,w,chooserows(choosecols(d,sequence(1,w,c)),sequence(h,1,r))),h,hstack(s(1,1,1,f),"Date","GroupID"),i,sequence(1,(columns(d)-f)/g,f+1,g),a,reduce(h,sequence(rows(d)-1,1,2),lambda(a,r,let(x,s(r,1,1,f),b,reduce(tocol(æ,2),i,lambda(y,c,let(z,s(r,c,1,g),if(""=+z,y,vstack(y,hstack(x,s(1,c,1,1),z)))))),vstack(a,b)))),if(k,a,choosecols(a,sequence(1,columns(a)-1,2))))), 

  unpivot_('Group History'!A2:ZZ, 1, 1) 
)

That will work until column ZZ but you can go all the way to ZZZ if required.
To get the matrix, insert another sheet and put this formula there:
=let( 
  students, tocol('Group History'!A3:A, 1), 
  data, filter(Unpivot!A2:C, len(Unpivot!A2:A)), 
  names, choosecols(data, 1), 
  dates, choosecols(data, 2), 
  groupIds, choosecols(data, 3), 
  matrix, map(students, lambda(s, let( 
    d, filter(dates, names = s), 
    i, filter(groupIds, names = s), 
    inSameGroup, filter(names, match(dates & groupIds, d & i, 0)), 
    counts, query(inSameGroup, "select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1", 0), 
    row, arrayformula(ifna(vlookup( 
      torow(students), counts, 2, false 
    ))), 
    arrayformula(if(torow(students) = s, "x", row)) 
  ))), 
  vstack( 
    hstack( 
      "in the same group on the same date", 
      torow(students) 
    ), 
    hstack(students, matrix) 
  ) 
)


See
let(),
lambda(),
map(),
vstack(),
hstack(),
choosecols(),
filter(),
vlookup(),
match(),
arrayformula(),
query(),
torow()
and
tocol().

Edited the answer to limit results to names in the same group on the same date.
